# WAMP vs. Live server facebook connect

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

I'm still trying to get my site working with Facebook Connect. I've been using the guide [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/).

The following code is run from localhost (**My app ID and secret ID have been removed**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<?php

define('YOUR_APP_ID', '**MY APP ID**');
define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', '**MY SECRET APP ID**');

$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(YOUR_APP_ID, YOUR_APP_SECRET);

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret) {
  $args = array();
  parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $app_secret) != $args['sig']) {
    return null;
  }
  return $args;
}



$user = json_decode(file_get_contents(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .
    $cookie['access_token']));

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<?php if ($cookie) { ?>
  <li> Welcome <?= $user->name ?></li>
<?php } else { ?>
  <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
<?php } ?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({appId: '<?= **MY APP ID** ?>', status: true,
           cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
  });
</script>
</html>
```

But gives me the following errors when I try to run it via WAMP:

```
Notice: Undefined index: fbs_**MY APP ID** in C:\wamp\www\fbtest.php on line 12
Notice: Undefined index: sig in C:\wamp\www\fbtest.php on line 20
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\wamp\www\fbtest.php on line 30
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Result too large in C:\wamp\www\fbtest.php on line 30
```

However, I suspected this might be a problem with WAMP. So I put this code live on a private server and got no errors like this... However, when I try to click the **Login** Facebook button, it opens a new window where it only tells me `An error occurred. Please try again later.`

I'm unsure how to resolve this either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if you send correct credentials to the javascript. It look like the url of you application or the appId is not correct or same as you filled in in the applications edit section. If you are running in Iframe, send this header, it will really help and you will not hit another problems.

```
Header('P3P: policyref="/p3p.xml", CP="IDC DSP COR IVAi IVDi OUR TST"');
```

With the WAMP. One problem is that you don't have support for https in file_get_contents. Is the error from the actual server or did you change the app id there as well?

If you will have still the problems, I can send you some small examples, so you can test them.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you fix the https problem, Facebook Connect does not work from localhost. The script needs to be executed from the domain where you have your Facebook app registered.